# Associative Entity with Multiple Foreign Keys?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Is it bad DB design to have an associative entity with multiple foreign keys?

In a scenario such as;

1 Truck is managed by 1 Team which goes to 1 particular route and has 1 Manager..etc

an associatve entity would be ideal in the above, is this bad design principle to do so?

Answer (score 0):

First off an associative entity is needed for many-to-many relationships, so you need to use `0,1 or many` in your description as opposed to `1 truck managed by 1 manager`.

Secondly, associative entities have multiple foreign keys (one for every entity they have are connected with). An associative entity is essentially a RELATIONSHIP where both sides have a many carnality:

> ```
> e.g. 0 or many trucks are managed by zero or many teams.
> ```

```
TEAM (TEAM_ID)
TRUCK (TRUCK_ID)
TRICK_MANAGEMENT_TEAMS (TEAM_ID, TRUCK_ID)
```

Comment: Should your trick_management_teams also have "route_id"? Just want to clarify that you can include multiple foreign keys (all examples I've seen have only had 2, even though it makes sense for them to have more since they are not attributes)

Comment: @silenceislife  I try not to make associative entities with 3 foreign keys (unless it is the result of further normalization). However, if it is the case that a team manages specific route instances with trucks that change, it would be valid to include 3 keys.